# Prove that each language in $NP$ has both properties with respect to polynomial reductions.

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

> For language $M ⊆ \{0, 1\}^*$ lets denote $And(M) = \#(M\#)^*$ and
> $Or(M)=\#\{0,1,\#\}^*\#M\#\{0,1,\#\}^*\#$.  We can say that language
> has $AND$ ($OR$) property  with respect to polynomial
> reductions if there exists polynomial reduction from $AND(M)$$(OR(M))$ to
> $M$. The same story about reductions in $L$ (logspace).
>
> Show that:
> each language  in $NP-complete$ has both properties with respect to polynomial reductions.

Can you help me solve it ? I have no idea.

**Edit**
Clarification of symbols:  $M$ is language over $\{0,1\}$, for example $M=0^n1^n=\{01, 0011, 000111,..\}$
$And(M)=\#(M\#)^* = \{\#, \#00001111\#01\#000111\#000111\#0011\#, \#0011\#01, \#01,...\}$

$\{0,1,\#\}^* = \{0111100\#\#\#\#, \#\#\#\#, \epsilon, 01010101, 01010\#01\#, 00000,11,....\}$

Comment: Define concretely those symbols : what means $M \subset \{0,1\}^*$ is a language (a formal grammar to generate it ? a Turing machine recognizing it ?) and what is $\# (M\#)^*$ and how it is related to $M$, and how being in NP is involved.

Comment: @reuns M is simply any language in this context. And the 'And' and 'Or' is definition of another language using the language M in such a way, that there are words from M separated by $\#$ . Basically, those definitions are saying "Every word separated by $\#$ is in M" and "There is at least one word between two $\#$ that is in M". And the question is whether for any language in NP there is a polynomial reduction from the And(M) and Or(M) language back to the original language M.

Comment: I edited and added details

Comment: Your clarification is far from being one. You can give an example, but only if it explains the general case. And so $\#$ is a 3rd letter, it doesn't mean a $0$ or a $1$ ? What means a language is in NP ?

Comment: @reuns it is very standard notation. NP - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)

Comment: So you are using # as a separator to represent lists of potential elements of $M$? And $And(M)$ comprises the lists of elements that are all in $M$? And $Or(M)$ comprises the lists that contain at least one element of $M$? And you are being asked to prove $And(M)$ and $Or(M)$ both admit a log-time or polynomial-time reduction to $M$ on the assumption that $M$ is in $NP$. That sounds very surprising to me. Where did you get the problem from?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In this case it is about only polynomial time. From my exam. I am preapring for it...

Comment: You do mention $L$ in your question which is why I mentioned "log-time", but I should have written "log-space". In any case are you sure that the assumption on $M$ is just $NP$ and not $NP$-complete?

Comment: @RobArthan it was my mistake. It was about NP-completness --edited

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try doing  it for $M = \mathsf{SAT}$ first.

Comment: What value has proving in for SAT? It was my first intuition as well, but then I realized I need to create back an instance of M, and once I reduce this to a complete problem, I certainly cant go back to reduce it to a non-complete problem. Or does somehow existence of reduction of this language for complete problem prove existence of reduction for other complexity classes inside NP, that are non-complete? I think the way we should go here is to prove these languages have the same asymptotic complexity as the original language, which means there must be polynomial reduction.

Answer (score 0):

**And(M)**:
You have a problem $M$. You can reduce it to 3-SAT. Now, you can "convert" your $And(3-SAT)$ to conjuction of formulas. I mean for example: 
$$And(3-SAT) = \#(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3)\#(x_4 \vee x_5 \vee x_6)\# \\ \text { to } (x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3) \wedge \#(x_4 \vee x_5 \vee x_6)\#$$

And now you can convert that to $M$ (becasue $M$ is NP-complete) and then run machine for $M$ for that.

---

**Or(M)**:
You can the similar thing as above. When you make a conjuction of formulas you use $\vee$ instead of $\wedge$. For example:
$$And(3-SAT) = \#(x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3)\#(x_4 \vee x_5 \vee x_6)\# \\ \text { to } (x_1 \vee x_2 \vee x_3) \vee \#(x_4 \vee x_5 \vee x_6)\#$$

Now, you have not a 3-CNF formula but you can convert it to satisfability-equivalent 3-CNF formula in polynomial time.

Then you also convert it to $M$.

---

I am not sure whether it is correct. Maybe does someone verify it?

Comment: You can just drop all the $3-$s. Neither your answer nor my hint leads to a logspace reduction.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't leads to a logspace reduction. But, it leads to polynomial reduction and it's sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it's sufficient. I wasn't saying that you were wrong, but a log-space reduction is still mentioned in the question and neither my hint nor your answer covers that (and I'd be surprised if a log-space reduction exists in all cases). You can simplify your solution by dropping all the "$3-$"s and just considering satisfiability for arbitrary formulas.

Comment: ok, but for polynomial reduction is ok my solution? (I admit that I used your hint)

Comment: Be my guest $\ddot{\smile}$!

Comment: ok, I'll be your guest! So the answer is... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since NP contains $M$, contains regular languages and is closed under concatenation and Kleene star, languages $And(M) = \#(M\#)^*$ and
$Or(M)=\#\{0,1,\#\}^*\#M\#\{0,1,\#\}^*\#$ are in NP.

Since $M$ is NP-hard, there is a reduction from $And(M)$ to $M$ and from $Or(M)$ to $M$.